# How can I get real value which pointer indicate after pointer operation?

Tags: c, pointers, operation

When I type code like this, I can see address works well.

But in real value I can get real value from that pointer after pointer operation.

Suggested result is same between old value and new value.

**Soucrce code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float value;
    float *pd;
    printf("input float value : ");
    scanf("%f", &value);
    pd = &value;
    printf("%d\n", pd);
    printf("%f\n", *pd);
    *(pd)++;
    printf("%d\n", pd);
    printf("%f\n", *pd);

    return 0;
}
```

**Expected result**

When I set value in float value, 'value' like 12.345

```
input float value : 12.345
1539432628
12.345000
1539432632
12.345000
```

**Actual result**

```
input float value : 12.345
1539432628
12.345000
1539432632
109143502767521792.000000
```

Comment: use `%p` for `printf("%d\n", pd);`

Comment: Please suggest an example of output you expect

Comment: Why the parens?

Comment: If address is 10000 , result is work like 10000,10004

Comment: @csavvy: To print a pointer with `%p`, it should be cast to `void *`: `printf("%p\n", (void *) pd);`.

Comment: but I have a problem in value. printf("%f\n", *pd); can't get good result after *(pd)++

Comment: If float variable value is 12.345 all *pd is printed like 12.345

Comment: It is unclear what question you are asking. After `pd = &vale;`, `pd` points at the single object `value`. Incrementing `pd` changes it to point to a location just after `value` in memory, but then `*pd` does not refer to any object defined by the C standard. Using `*pd` to access that memory has behavior not defined by the standard. The standard does not define what will happen when you try to print it with `printf("%f\n", *pd);`. And you do not tell us what result you expect or what result you actually get, so we do not know what you are seeing or why you think it is wrong.

Comment: but I can't get 12.345 after pointer operation. so how to get correct value after pointer operation?

Comment: @EqualLove please [edit] the question and show an example of output you expect.

Comment: As you can see `1539432628` is first address and `1539432632` is the incremented address and we can't guess value in it

Comment: Between the first `printf("%f\n", *pd)` and the second one the `pd` pointer changes (it no longer points to `value` but somewhere else), so why do you expect that the second printf prints the same value as the first one?

Comment: In my book , example output is like that.

Comment: @EqualLove either you misunderstood something in the book, or you should burn the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are expecting is wrong.

`pd = &value;` stores the address of `value` in `pd`

Accessing `*pd`  gives the value inside variable `value` i.e `12.345`

Now using `*(pd)++;`, you are increase the address of `pd` so that it points to next location, now `pd`  is **not** pointing to `value` and the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Yes, but when I set the variable value "12.345" I want get 12.345 after pointer operation

Comment: @EqualLove please edit the question and show an example of output you expect.

Comment: In first printf, I can get value 12.345 without any problems. but second printf, I got a trash value anytime.

Comment: But that is meaning less. you are just pointing to one single float value ,increasing address will take you to next address which you are not supposed to access.

Answer (score 1):

The comments I added should explain exactly what happens.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float value;
    float *pd;
    printf("input float value : ");
    scanf("%f", &value);

    pd = &value;                // pd points to the variable value
    printf("%p\n", (void*)pd);  // correct way to print pointer values
    printf("%f\n", *pd);        // print the value pointed by pd, in other words
                                // print value
    pd++;                       // *(pd)++ is just a convoluted way to say pd++

    printf("%d\n", pd);         // print new pd pointer (which should be 4 higher)

    printf("%f\n", *pd);        // print value pointed by pd (which now no longer points to 
                                // value but points 4 bytes further

    printf("%f\n", *(pd - 1));  // should print the value because pd - 1 points
                                // to value
    return 0;
}
```

If you wonder why it's `*(pd - 1)` and not `*(pd - 4)` in the code above, google *c pointer arithmetic*.